# Customer action does not executed

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

When I run rasa sample code *(rasa run actions & rasa shell)* that *action.py* part does not work (custom action not work). So, could you give any solution to fix the problem

> Failed to run custom action ‘find_facility_types’

Added the custom action into the domain. But, the actual problem is **when I execute the “rasa run actions” command that executing** but, that not completed.
I attached the execution time [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B5Ya.jpg)

> (snake-rasa) C:\Users\Pavucs\Desktop\knowledgebasebot>rasa run actions
>   2020-01-23 08:39:45.626889: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44]
>   Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
>
> 2020-01-23 08:39:47 INFO rasa_sdk.endpoint - Starting action endpoint
>   server… 2020-01-23 08:39:47 INFO rasa_sdk.executor - Registered
>   function for ‘action_query_knowledge_base’.

finally, I got this result (uncompleted)

```
os:windows,
Rasa 1.6.1,
Rasa_sdk 1.6.1,
Python 3.6.10,
en-core-web-md 2.2.5,
en-core-web-sm 2.2.5,
sanic 19.9.0,
```

Answer (score 0):

I would need more information around what your action code is doing, you can also put debugs in and I would expect if you ran rasa shell --debug you might see a little more as well from the rasa side.

You don't have any errors from the actions console other than just that `Failed to run custom action ‘find_facility_types’` is happening?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! This not how we answer questions here. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Use comments to ask for additional information from OP.